# can figure out the problem with my realloc inside the function

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that needs to call a function that adds numbers until -1 is introduced, the problem is that after 3 numbers the program stops and gives segmentation fault:

```
int leNumeros(int **lista, int *nElem, int *tam)
{
    int op, *temp = NULL;
    *lista = (int*) malloc(*tam * sizeof(int));

    if(*lista == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory fail\n");
    } else
    {
        do
        {
            printf("number:\n");
            scanf("%d",&op);

            if(op >= 0)
            {
                if(*nElem >= *tam)
                {
                *lista = (int*) realloc( *lista, *nElem * sizeof(int) );

                if(*lista == NULL)
                {
                    printf("memory fail");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("added: %d bytes total: %d bytes\n",
                            *nElem * sizeof(int), *nElem * sizeof(int) + *tam * sizeof(int));
                    //*lista = temp;
                }
                }
                *lista[*nElem] = op;
                (*nElem)++;



            }
        }while(op >= 0);
    }    
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int *lista = NULL, nElem = 0, tam = 0;

    leNumeros(&lista, &nElem, &tam);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding what is going on, can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is `*nElem` the first time you call `realloc()`?

Comment: `*lista = (int*) realloc( *lista, *nElem * sizeof(int) );` You need to increment `*nElem` before calling this.

Comment: nElem is the number of elements, i tried to increase before calling realloc and didnt work

Comment: _nElem is the number of elements_ What is `*tam`?

Comment: still didnt work, ather 3 times stops and gives segmentation fault and also tam is "size" this exercise is from a teacher and after hours of trying to figure out the problem i ended up removing it from the program

Comment: I don't think the 3rd parameter is supposed to be `0`. I guess it's the initial block size to allocate and/or the amount to reallocate.

Comment: Another issue: `*lista[*nElem] = op;` should be `(*lista)[*nElem] = op;`

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code, watch the arguments, the errors become are obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `leNumeros()` is called you attempt to allocate a zero length block - that has *implementation defined behaviour*.

Then when you enter a number > 0, you attempt to `realloc()` a zero length block - that behaviour is *well defined* it frees the original block then returns a null pointer, then at `*lista[*nElem] = op;` you deference that null pointer rather than aborting the loop.

In any event `*lista[*nElem] = op;` should be `(*lista)[*nElem] = op;`

Even if  `*nElem` was non-zero, the line:

```
*lista = (int*)realloc(*lista, *nElem * sizeof(int));
```

is bad-practice, because if the reallocation fails the original block will leak because *lista will be come NULL without releasing whatever it previously pointed to.  Instead you should (for example):

```
int* new_block = realloc(*lista, *nElem * sizeof(int));
if( new_block == NULL )
{
    printf( "memory fail\n" ) ;
    break ;
}

*lista = new_block ;
```

To work at all in main `tam` must be > 0, and to avoid possible failure due to implementation defined behaviour `nElem` should also be grater than zero.

Comment: ty so much!!! finally i spent almost the entire day trying to solve this, ty

Answer (score 1):

I think the `tam` parameter is probably the block size to allocate. So for example, if tam = 10, allocate space for 10 ints. Then after taking 10 ints, realloc for 10 more.

Also, note that because of operator precedence, `*lista[*nElem] = op;` is the same as `*(lista[*nElem]) = op;`. You want to deference the pointer first, then use the brackets: `(*lista)[*nElem] = op;`

```
void leNumeros(int **lista, int *nElem, int *tam)
{
    if (*tam <= 0) {
        puts("Error: tam must be > 0");
        return;
    }

    int op;

    // Keep track of how many ints the array can hold
    int items_allocated = *tam;
    *lista = malloc(*tam * sizeof(int));

    if (*lista == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory fail\n");
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            printf("number:\n");
            if (1 != scanf("%d", &op)) break;

            if (op >= 0) {
                // Realloc a new block of tam bytes if out of space
                if (*nElem >= items_allocated) {
                    items_allocated += *tam;
                    int *temp = realloc(*lista, items_allocated * sizeof(int));

                    if (temp == NULL) {
                        printf("memory fail");
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        *lista = temp;
                        printf("added: %zu bytes total: %zu bytes\n", *tam * sizeof(int), items_allocated * sizeof(int));
                    }
                }
                (*lista)[*nElem] = op;
                (*nElem)++;
            }
        } while (op >= 0);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int *lista = NULL, nElem = 0, tam = 5;
    leNumeros(&lista, &nElem, &tam);

    for (int i = 0; i < nElem; i++) {
        printf("%d ", lista[i]);
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```